# Generate random numbers until divisible by 5

Tags: c#, do-while

> Random numbers from 10 to 60 are generated until the number is divisible by 5. This number should be displayed on the screen. Show trial number and average value

I START WITH :

```
int a;
do
{

    Random rnd = new Random();
    a = rnd.Next(10, 60);


}while
```

BUT I THINK  its wrong

Comment: It's wrong because it is incomplete. You aren't doing anything but getting a random number. Where are you storing averages? Where are you doing your divisible checks? Where are you printing the number? What is the condition of the loop?

Comment: put condition on your while

Comment: Move `Random rnd = new Random();` outside your loop or else you are going to generate the same numbers over and over.

Comment: I do not want nobody working for me tasks, I just have no idea how to set the formulas to get the number divided by 5 I tried while (a / 5), but not

Comment: you should pull the declaration and assignment of `rnd` out of the loop. you only need to create it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
var rnd = new Random();
var number = 0;

do
{
    number = rnd.Next(10, 60);
    numbers.Add(number);
    Console.WriteLine($"Number: {number}, Average: {numbers.Average()}");

} while (number % 5 != 0);
```

Updated: to actually address the random element of the question.

Comment: I think this is true, it seems that there is nothing from me and my learning, all the time I thought it was a loop to do  while in question

Comment: The most important part of homework and exams is to read the question. There is nothing random about this

Comment: " until the number is divisible by 5" also hints at an exit condition

Comment: I thought he needed to rotate  the numbers until he found the first divisible  with 5 and stopped the program

Comment: I THINK  i find solution and finaly finish,tnx all for  helping

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer? There are no random numbers being chosen here, and they continue to be chosen after one is found that's divisible by 5. That's two rule violations right there! I hope this isn't homework!

Comment: no its not homework, i just trying to finish internet questions about c#             ty pmcilreavy i same do like you,
you've helped me most with this code "var number = 0;

Answer (score 0):

That given code won't compile. Put a condition in that will exit the do while loop when `a` is divisible by 5: `while (condition that will exit)` **Hint: check the modulus operator**

> Also, read the question: *average value*

You want to keep a list of the numbers you have tried to check for division by 5 and report the average at the end.

`var numbersTried = new List<int>();`

`numbersTried.Add(a);`

`var average = numbersTried.Average();`

Finally, report the value `a` after the do while loop, which will be the first number between 10 and 60 that is divisible by 5.

```
Console.WriteLine($"First number divisble by 5 is {a}");
Console.WriteLine($"Average of numbers tried is {average}");
```

Comment: No, not here to do your homework, got to learn by trying. There is more than enough hints. Try again and I will give more hints

Comment: You can't go to the pub yet until you finish! haha

Comment: I do not want nobody working for me tasks, I just have no idea how to set the formulas to get the number divided by 5 I tried while (a / 5), but not

Comment: This answer was in the deletion queue, but the does actually answer one of the two problems in the question and heavily hints the answer to the other. Not sure if "homework" is a reason to delete a question?

Comment: I was trying to provide hints and work along with him but if it constitutes plain homework cheating, then nuke it from orbit. I believe the OP was trying at least.

Comment: I did not have any tasks, I just looked at the internet and tried to rescue myself,
I apologize if I offend anyone or the like, but it is misunderstood

Comment: @Luke Your answer was in the deletion queue, I'm surprised it wasn't the question to be honest. I deemed you gave valid answer and left a comment for others explaining why. I see what what you are doing :) I've checked meta and nothing says the validity of the question based on it being homework so, as you were. *p.s. you have more rep than me don't be scared!*

Comment: hehe ya all good, could be someone upset perhaps I'm giving an answer to homework

Comment: @Luke my view is that even if a Q&A might not help other people, it's nice that someone might get help from someone even if it won't gain them rep, but they might gain... call it good karma, or call it abiding by different guidelines *ahem https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice* so wishing you some good karma

Comment: Cheers, thanks, ya I do tend to see the community is hard on newbie questions especially around homework questions, but I do see the OP is trying. I think giving a full code answer is not good for homework questions however.

Comment: Sometimes the whole code helps to understand the task, I know that I'm at the beginning and everything I've learned so far is through youtoba and some sites, it would be nice to have someone who would sit next to me and tell me why something is the way it is

Comment: Yah, this topic is more talked about on meta, checkout https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: TNX ALL FOR HELPING i think i find solution

Answer (score 0):

```
int a;
Random rnd = new Random();
do
{
  a = rnd.Next(10, 60);

}while(a % 5==0)
```